# How can this limp hot pepper plant be saved?

Tags: watering, peppers, repotting

I recently repotted my pepper plant, and ever since, it's suffering from limp leaves.

My guess is that I did too much damage to the roots when repotting. Supporting this theory is the fact that when I put the plant into a bucket of water for a few days, it did recover. However, I obviously couldn't leave it in water forever, and since I put it back in the pot, it's been going limp again.

Can I do anything to save the plant? Pruning it to reduce the amount of water required springs to mind, but I have no idea if that's actually benefitial or if the stress of pruning will actually be more harmful than helpful.

I wager that I could probably take it out of the pot again and put it back in a bucket of water, but that will likely do some more damage to the roots no matter how careful I am. Besides, if it's not getting enough water while potted, it's likely not getting enough nutrients either. And whereas it might get enough water while in the bucket, it's definitely getting zero nutrients there, which means it will eventually run out.

I'm also curious whether exposing it to more or less sunlight is better (more available energy vs more loss of water via transpiration).

---

Images:

After the first repotting (= first sign of "limping"), 14. April:
[image]

The "bucket setup" just after putting it in (I don't have images of the recovered plant, unfortunately):
[image]

The plant as of now (24. April):
[image]

Comment: upon reviewing my question, it occured to me that "limp hot pepper plant" sounds like a lame "red hot chili peppers" rip-off xD

Comment: update: the plant eventually lost all leaves, but subsequently recovered and is now sporting a full set of leaves again :)